# Show annotation title automatically

Tags: swift, mkmapview, mkannotation

I'm trying to display the annotation title automatically instead of displaying it on tap. I used the below code to display annotation and make it center on map.

```
self.ann.setCoordinate(currentLocation2D)
self.ann.title = "Title"
self.ann.subtitle = "Subtitle"
self.mapView.addAnnotation(self.ann);

self.span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.005, 0.005)
self.region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: currentLocation2D, span: self.span)
self.mapView.setRegion(self.region, animated: true)
```

I get to see the `title`, `subtitle` and `CalloutAccessoryView` when I tap the annotation but couldn't able to display it automatically.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use it by using `selectAnnotation` and use the `mapview.annotations` array, which contains all your `annotations` which you have on your map.

```
let yourAnnotationAtIndex = 0
mapView.selectAnnotation(mapView.annotations[yourAnnotationAtIndex], animated: true)
```

Comment: It is add title for 1 annotation, how to show title for all annotations?

Comment: @DuyenHangKim did you find the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

```
mapView.selectAnnotation(mapView.annotations[0], animated: true)
```